Reverse proxy for streamlit
Streamlit app
I have a streamlit app running on port 8501:
https://dharmatech.dev:8501/fed-net-liquidity/

Here's how I'm starting the app:
streamlit run \
        --browser.serverAddress dharmatech.dev \
        --browser.serverPort 8501 \
        --server.sslCertFile /home/dharmatech/fullchain.pem \
        --server.sslKeyFile /home/dharmatech/privkey.pem \
        --server.baseUrlPath fed-net-liquidity \
        Fed_Net_Liquidity.py

Apache configuration
Here's the contents of /etc/apache2/sites-available/dharmatech.dev-le-ssl.conf:
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dharmatech.dev
    ServerName dharmatech.dev
    ServerAlias www.dharmatech.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dharmatech.dev
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dharmatech.dev/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dharmatech.dev/privkey.pem

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /fed-net-liquidity/(.*)         wss://dharmatech.dev:8501/fed-net-liquidity/$1 [P,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /fed-net-liquidity/(.*)           https://dharmatech.dev:8501/fed-net-liquidity/$1 [P,L]

    SSLProxyEngine on
    #ProxyPass        /fed-net-liquidity https://dharmatech.dev:8501/fed-net-liquidity
    ProxyPassReverse /fed-net-liquidity https://dharmatech.dev:8501/fed-net-liquidity


    #ProxyPass        /fed-net-liquidity wss://dharmatech.dev:8501/fed-net-liquidity
    ProxyPassReverse /fed-net-liquidity wss://dharmatech.dev:8501/fed-net-liquidity


</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

Results
When I go to:
https://dharmatech.dev/fed-net-liquidity/
here's the result:

Question
What's a good way to set up the proxy so that
https://dharmatech.dev/fed-net-liquidity/
results in the app being properly rendered?
apache2ctl -S output:
$ sudo apache2ctl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  dharmatech.dev (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dharmatech.dev-le-ssl.conf:2)
*:80                   dharmatech.dev (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dharmatech.dev.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33


Your backend  server sends the redirect. Configure it to not do that. Usually you can configure a base URL.

Hi @GeraldSchneider ‍♂️. By backend server, do you mean the streamlit application on port 8105? I checked the command-line options for it and I didn't see one that seems to be related to redirection.

@GeraldSchneider I think one thing I may need to update the config for websockets. I've added a section to the question on that. I'm now getting a slightly different result.

You can configure your streamlit server with a base URL with config.toml: https://docs.streamlit.io/develop/api-reference/configuration/config.toml#server

Yup, I went back to using a base URL. I've updated the question with the results.

For websocket proxy, see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#wsupgrade

i try quick answer ...
change streamlit host to local all https will be handle by  apache
streamlit run 
--browser.serverAddress localhost 
--browser.serverPort 8501 
Fed_Net_Liquidity.py
Using localhost .
change reverse proxy :
RewriteRule /fed-net-liquidity/(.*)         wss://localhost:8501/fed-net-liquidity/$1 [P,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /fed-net-liquidity/(.*)           http://localhost:8501/fed-net-liquidity/$1 [P,L]
SSLProxyEngine on

#ProxyPass        /fed-net-liquidity http://localhost:8501/fed-net-liquidity

ProxyPassReverse /fed-net-liquidity http://localhost:8501/fed-net-liquidity

#ProxyPass        /fed-net-liquidity wss://localhost:8501/fed-net-liquidity

ProxyPassReverse /fed-net-liquidity wss://localhost:8501/fed-net-liquidity                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>


so let me know when can help opzteams

Hey Ops team ‍♂️. I've setup a similar config and updated the question with the results.

can change to localhost without https

The streamlit server is running on https.

can change streamlit to working http  since all https will be handle apache , except you open port 8501 but will be looping

Aha... I see what you mean.

for wss should ws not wss ?

sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_balancer proxy_wstunnel proxy_http
command to enabe wstunnel

OK, I setup http on the backend and the issue is still occurring. But thank you for the suggestion!

just like this  [streamlit] (https://streamlit.aichat.host) @dharmatech

For this particular use case, I'd like to keep the streamlit app on https as well. For example, you can access this site right now https://dharmatech.dev:8501/fed-net-liquidity/

I got it working. See this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/1159261/102828 The key was --server.enableCORS false.

The key was to add --server.enableCORS false when running streamlit.
Here's how I'm starting streamlit:
streamlit run \
        --browser.serverPort 8501 \
        --server.sslCertFile /home/dharmatech/fullchain.pem \
        --server.sslKeyFile /home/dharmatech/privkey.pem \
        --server.baseUrlPath fed-net-liquidity \
        --server.enableCORS false \
        Fed_Net_Liquidity.py

The apache configuration file located at:
/etc/apache2/sites-available/dharmatech.dev-le-ssl.conf

contains:
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dharmatech.dev
    ServerName dharmatech.dev
    ServerAlias www.dharmatech.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dharmatech.dev
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dharmatech.dev/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dharmatech.dev/privkey.pem

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /fed-net-liquidity/(.*)         wss://dharmatech.dev:8501/fed-net-liquidity/$1 [P,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /fed-net-liquidity/(.*)           https://dharmatech.dev:8501/fed-net-liquidity/$1 [P,L]

    SSLProxyEngine on
    #ProxyPass        /fed-net-liquidity https://dharmatech.dev:8501/fed-net-liquidity
    ProxyPassReverse /fed-net-liquidity https://dharmatech.dev:8501/fed-net-liquidity


    #ProxyPass        /fed-net-liquidity wss://dharmatech.dev:8501/fed-net-liquidity
    ProxyPassReverse /fed-net-liquidity wss://dharmatech.dev:8501/fed-net-liquidity


</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

